# SettingWithCopyWarning when executing panda query

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df1 with a column name "col1" and "col2". I want to update value in col2 based on certain condition in col1. I executing below piece of code but getting error:

> SettingWithCopyWarning:
> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
>
> See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

here's my code:
[image: code]

How to get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using chain indexing:

```
df["col2"].iloc[query_index]
```

It's really to tell in advance which of these two returns a copy or a view into the underlying dataframe. Hence the warning.

Your problem can be solved with built-in vectorized functions:

```
df["col2"] = df["col2"].where(~df["col1"].isin(list1), df["col1"])
```

When a row in `col2` is not in `list1`, keep its original value, else use the value from `col1`.

Comment: getting error "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead"